# I can partially display my content (displaying firstName instead of firstName and lastName)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

how can I do to display `firstName` and `lastName` for `People` and `Invitees` colums?
Because for now I can display `firstName` for column `People` (i.e `Eliot` instead of `Eliot Gray`); for column `Invitees`-> `firstName` and `lastName`  are attached together (i.e `Paul Poel` instead of `PaulPoel`)  .

```
export default function Meeting() {
  ...
  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: (row) => row.id
      },
      {
        Header: "People",
        accessor: (row) => row.people[0].firstName && row.people[0].lastName
      },
      {
        Header: "Invitees",
        accessor: (row) => row.invitees,
        Cell: (props) =>
          props.value !== [] && props.value.length > 0 ? (
            <div>
              {props.value !== []
                ? props.value
                    .map(({ firstName, lastName }) => firstName && lastName)
                    .join(", ")
                : ""}
              {props.value.length > 0 && (
                <CloseIcon
                  text={
                    props.value !== []
                      ? props.value.map((o) => (
                          <span key={o.firstName}>
                            <b>{o.firstName}</b>
                            <b>{o.lastName}</b>
                          </span>
                        ))
                      : ""
                  }
                />
              )}
            </div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <Table
      data={meeting}
      columns={data}          
    />
  );
}
```

My json :

```
{
  "meeting": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "people": [
        {
          "firstName": "Eliot",
          "lastName": "Gray"
        },
        ...
      ],
      "invitees": [
        {
          "firstName": "Paul",
          "lastName": "Poel"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you need to display the name as `${firstName} ${lastName}` i.e "Paul Poel"?

Comment: @reflexgravity, Yes same issue for "Eliot Gray", i want to display like this "Eliot Gray, Other People1, Other People2..."

Answer (score 0):

If you want display `firstName` and `lastName` together for `People`, append the names and return it.

Same goes for `Invities` too, instead of using `&&` use `+` to append and return it.
`&&` will return the value of last operand until it turns `false`

According to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

> The logical AND (&&) operator (logical conjunction) for a set of boolean operands will be true if and only if all the operands are true. Otherwise it will be false. More generally, the operator returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all truthy.

```
{
  Header: "People",
  accessor: (row) => row.people[0].firstName + " " + row.people[0].lastName
}
```